# Live search results showing on new page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, search

I hope someone can help me, I have an live Ajax Jquery search bar. Now my search bar shows no more then 5 results. What I want is an button below the live results with 'More results', and if you click this button you go to a new page and see all te results of your search.

What I have tried is to put an submit button below the row results, but then he put all the names of the results into the search insteady of the text from the input.

PHP:

```
    <form action="./s/" method="GET">
    <div class="searchbox">
        
        <!-- SEARCHBOX INPUT -->
        <input type="text" name="s" class="searchbox-input" placeholder="Search trough 1,000 games in our database.." name="name" />

        <div class="searchbox-line"></div>
        <div class="searchbox-icon">
            <input class="img-searchbox-icon" name="" value="" type="submit">
        </div>

        <div class="results"></div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

MySQL:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY name LIMIT 5";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_term = '%' . $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                    echo '<a href="' . $row["url"] . '">';
                    echo '<p class="results-name">' . $row["name"] . '</a></p>';

                    echo '<p class="results-platform">';
                    echo '<img class="platform" src="img/platform-icons/' . $row["platform1"] . '.png" />';
                    echo '<img class="platform" src="img/platform-icons/' . $row["platform2"] . '.png" />';
                    echo '<img class="platform" src="img/platform-icons/' . $row["platform3"] . '.png" />';
                    echo '<img class="platform" src="img/platform-icons/' . $row["platform4"] . '.png" />';
                    echo '<img class="platform" src="img/platform-icons/' . $row["platform5"] . '.png" />';
                    echo '<img class="platform" src="img/platform-icons/' . $row["platform6"] . '.png" />';
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            } else{
                echo '<p class="results-gamename">No matches found</p>';
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add more details? Your question is too vague at this moment.

Comment: Dear Kay, what I have now is that when you typ in the search bar 5 results when you search (live results). Now I want a text or button below the 5 results with 'show more results'. When you click on this you go to search.php and there you will see all the results (more then 5, if there are more then 5). I have put a submit button after the 'row' echo's but then he will search on all the result names and not on the keyword I put in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll take a shot at this. In your HTML file (the one you originally named 'PHP') you've declared the form like this:

```
<form action="./s/" method="GET">
```

And you've given your search input the following name:

```
<input type="text" name="s" class="..." placeholder="..." name="name" />
```

Hence, when you send through the form, your input field will be sent through with the name 'name', since you've double declared its name. It'll fallback to the last 'name' attribute you've given to the element.